# Undefined Variable in view, Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am very new in Laravel. I have made a controller. And there I have declared a variable. I want to pass it to a view. But it says variable undefined.

this is the controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function about(){
        $name= 'XYZ';
        return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name);
    }
}
```

this is the view

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title"> About Me: {!! $name !!}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `::` after Me remove it. Also use `About Me: {!! $name !!}`

Comment: You need to include the code (in text) in the body of your question rather than images.

Comment: I tried this too. Still the same problem :\

Comment: What is `\App\Http\Controllers\PagesController about` why is it outside of `<?php` tag? It's best you add your code here

Comment: That's not code, that's part of the editor's UI and the `::` shouldn't matter.  It's just text.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Solved it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try and return your data to the view like this:

```
return View::make('pages.about' , array(
            'name' => $name
        ));
```

Then echo the data in the view with blade like this:

```
<div class="title"> About Me: {{ $name }} </div>
```